# error: request for member ‘...’ in something not a structure or union in C

Tags: c

I am writing the Structure of Queue in a header file, and defined a Function to manipulate the Queue in "qFucntion.c".

**Header file**

```
struct QueueTree{
   int element[n];
   int size;
   ...
};

typedef struct QueueTree *Qt;
```

**qFunction.c**

```
#include "Header File"
Qt * createQueueTree(){
   Qt *q;
   q->size = 0;
   return q;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "Header File"
void main(){
   Qt *q = createQueueTree(); 
}
```

The problem is, once I run the "main.c". The error is shown below.

> error: request for member ‘size’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: That is why we tell don't typedef pointers...check the data type..

Comment: Not to mention to don't initialize `q`, so the behavior of `q->size = 0;` is undefined.

Comment: type of `q` is `struct Queque**`, not `struct Queque*`. So pointer `q` doesn't have member of `size`. Also maybe `struct Queue` typo as `struct QueueTree`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am happy to see that you comment with full sentences. There was nothing wrong with your code fix posts before but I like to see that you feel more comfortable writing english (given your description on your userpage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `typedef struct Queue *Qt;` you are creating the typedef for the structure pointer. After this you are creating `Qt *q;` which inturn means `struct Queue **q;` which doesnt have a member called size.  `typedef struct Queue Qt;` can solve your error.